# Development versus Production in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I want to understand how people are handing an update to a production app on the Parse.com platform. Here is the scenario that I am not sure about.

1. Create an called myApp_DEV. The app contains a database as well as associated cloud code.
2. Once testing is complete and ready for go-live I will clone this app into myApp_PRD (Production version). Cloning it will copy all the database as well as the cloud code.

So far so good.

Now 3 months down the line I want have added some functionality which includes adding some cloud code functions as well as adding some new columns to the tables in the db.

How do I update myApp_PRD with these new database structure. If i try to clone it from my DEV app it tells me the app all ready exists.

If I clone a new app (say myApp_PRD2) from DEV then all the data will be lost since the customer is all ready live.

Any ideas on how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Sadly we haven't found a solution to this other than just copying cloud code by hand to a production application from our test project.

Comment: @Dusker, I'd upvote if it wasn't so sad that it's all that we can do at the moment, haha. Remember Alon, you'll also have to add the new columns to your production database as well as copying over the cloud code

Answer (score 2):

Cloud code supports deploying to production and development environments.

You'll first need to link your production app to your existing cloud code. this can be done in the command line:

`parse add production`

When you're ready to release, it's a simple matter of:

`parse deploy production`

See the [Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#hosting-development-vs-production) for all the details.

As for the schema changes, I guess we just have to manually add all the new columns.